# How do I define a static constexpr array member of a template class specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, clang, static-members, constexpr

I am attempting to use static constexpr arrays within a template specialised class as shown below:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct good {
    static constexpr int values[1] = { 0 };
};

constexpr int good::values[1];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename T>
struct bad;

template <>
struct bad<int> {
    static constexpr int values[1] = { 0 };  
};

constexpr int bad<int>::values[1];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
#if 1
    return good::values[0];
#else
    return bad<int>::values[0];
#endif
}
```

I am aware of the requirement to both declare and define static members, and the 'good' case from above appears to succeed with gcc-6.2.0 and clang-3.9.0 using -std=c++1z.

However the 'bad' case results in an undefined reference under clang-3.9.0, giving the output as follows:

```
danny@steve ~/src $ clang++ -std=c++1z scratch.cpp
/tmp/scratch-56fa44.o: In function `main':
scratch.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `bad<int>::values'
clang-3.9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there something additional I need to do, or that I'm missing, to instantiate static constexpr members? The code appears to work fine when modified to use static const members.

The code will link successfully if the unit is instead compiled with -std=c++1y.

Comment: Interesting, `g++ --std=c++11` compiles and runs it just fine.

Comment: @skypjack I don't have a local copy of clang-HEAD, but a brief spot of testing at http://melpon.org/wandbox/ using clang-HEAD and c++1z shows an identical message to what I'm seeing under clang-3.9.0

Comment: @dcro My fault. Didn't see you used c++1z. Sorry.

Comment: File a bug report. This suspiciously coincides with clang's inline variables implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something additional I need to do, or that I'm missing, to instantiate static `constexpr` members?

The code looks well formed, but it indeed fails to link in Clang up to version 5.0.2, however it is fully accepted in Clang 6.0. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ka7W4bbqf

This suggests that it was just a compiler bug.